# Limits algebra. Prove $a_n$ converges and find its limit.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $0<a_0<1$, $a_{n+1}=a_n-{a_n}^3$. Prove $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges and find its limit.

What I did so far is: Let us show that $a_n>0$ by induction on $n$. The case $n=0$ is clear. Let us assume it holds for $n$ and show it does for $n+1$. $a_n>0 \Rightarrow a_{n-1}-{a_{n-1}}^3 >0 \Rightarrow a_{n-1}>{a_{n-1}}^3 \Rightarrow a_{n-1}<1 \Rightarrow a_{n-1}-{a_{n-1}}^3<1 \Rightarrow a_n<1 \Rightarrow a_n>{a_n}^3 \Rightarrow a_{n+1}=a_n-{a_n}^3>0.$

Now $a_n-a_{n+1}={a_n}^3>0 \Rightarrow $ $\{a_n\}$ is non-increasing. Since $a_n>0$ then is is a nonincreasing lower bounded sequence and therefore converges to $L$.

This is where I am not that sure in what I am doing: $\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_{n}}=L$. $\lim_{n\to \infty}-{a_{n}}^3=-(\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_{n}})^3=-L^3$. Therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n}-\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n}^3 \Rightarrow L=L-L^3 \Rightarrow L=0$. Is that admissible?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you for your evaluation.